# How to skip certain elements when using javascript map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have this bit of code to split up a string and display it as a list.

```
<span className="reply">{this.props.message.split("\n").map((chunk) => {
    return <span className="message-chunk">{chunk}<br /></span>
})}
```

I want to skip the first and last element in the split array because the string is of the form.

```
Heading\n
List Item\n
List Item\n
List Item\n
Ending\n
```

Is there a way to do this while using the map function. I saw mention of the `filter()` function in another related question but I don't think that's applicable here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean "skip" as in still return the heading and end but transform everything else, or only return the list items?

Comment: @vlaz I mean the first

Comment: @user3282276 If one of the answers is correct please mark it as so. If none of them are please provide feedback as to how it does not solve your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to just [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the array before you map, so in your case it would be:

```
this.props.message.split("\n").slice(1, -1).map((chunk) => {
    return <span className="message-chunk">{chunk}<br /></span>
})
```

Note that this will  remove the first and last element from the array. If you are intending to not modify the first or last element I recommend @vlaz's answer :)

Comment: slice doesn't mutate the array, but returns a new one, so this is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

The callback function for [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will be passed three parameters - the element, the index, and the array. So you can very easily skip the first and last element when transforming

```
arr.map(function(item, index, list) {
    if(index === 0 || index === list.length -1) {
         return item;
    } else {
        /* transformation logic */
        return transformedItem;
    }

})
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the first and last element are still in the returned array

Comment: OP said _skip_ them which I took to mean they still need to be returned. Perhaps the requirement is to remove them but it's not totally clear.

Answer (score 1):

A pretty clean solution would be to store the line separated array. Then `.shift()` and `.pop()` it to trim edges (and store them if you need to), and iterate the trimmed array with `.map()`. :)

```
// Example with stored heading and ending
let messageLines = this.props.message.split("\n");
const heading = messageLines.shift();
const ending = messageLines.pop();

// Map whenever you need to
messageLines.map(...);
```